# Return datatable or xml from webservice?

Tags: xml, web-services, datatable, dataset, asmx

I am designing a C# webservice, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for outputting a single customer record ?

It currently returns a DataTable (and it works very well), but is this the 'normal' approach, or should I use a DataRow, a DataSet or simply construct a plain old XML output.

Comment: "(and it works very well),"   So now you want to break it?

Comment: BTW, is this a WCF service, or a legacy ASMX service?

Comment: @John it is currently ASMX, but after posting this I am thinking I should be using WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services are, ideally, platform-agnostic. In general, it's not a best practice to return `DataTable` or other types that are specific to .NET. Your clients may not be able to deal with them.

If you're just returning a single customer, then just return it. If you're returning a list of customers, then just return the list:

```
[OperationContract]
public Customer GetCustomer(int id);

[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
```

WCF will serialize this properly, in a way that permits your clients to handle the return.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't known about WCF before. I spent yesterday looking into it and think now I should abandon the asmx approach.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you even _consider_ ASMX? Were you led by a search result?

Comment: Simply limited experience - I haven't written a webservice since 2008 and I didn't realise the tech had moved on.
I see now that I can do away with the DataTable approach, but I'm now wondering if I should return a Customer type or plain XML. It is only me consuming the service, but I want to do it 'the right way' as opposed to just 'getting it to work'. Is there a best practice, or is it down to personal preference? - thanks.

Comment: Return the Customer type (or whatever Data Contract type you like). WCF will serialize it for you, and almost all clients will be able to consume it. The nice thing about Data Contracts is that, because they're a high-level description of what is meant to be serialized, WCF is much more likely to be able to serialize it so that any client can receive it. This is in contrast to XML Serialization, which gives you the flexibility to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with C# webservices, returning a DataTable to your front end is fairly standard practice.

If you're returning a single record, XML is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Everything will depends on the client that you are expecting, some return types are not available on all devices, for that i try to always return custom class.

But if your end works well with datatables, use it    i have see datatables as a return type on a lot of production code